# How to connect Azure Log Analytic Workspace using managed identity from .Net API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-log-analytics, azure-managed-identity

There is a workaround which is using azure active directory app permissions for connecting with azure log analytic workspace from c#. But whether the same can be achieved through managed identity instead of using Active Directory.

Reference : https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sentinel-blog/access-azure-sentinel-log-analytics-via-api-part-1/ba-p/1248377.

Comment: Managed identities are just managed service principals (Active directory object) so it should work. create the identity / give it the right permission and use the azure.identity package to acquire a token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a **User Assigned Managed Identity**:

[image]

Granted **Log  Analytics API permission** by using the below PowerShell script:

```
Connect-AzureAD

$TenantID="TenantID"
$LogAppId = "ca7f3f0b-7d91-482c-8e09-c5d840d0eac5" --> Dont change this value
$NameOfMSI="testrukMI"
$PermissionName = "Data.Read"

$MSI = (Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$NameOfMSI'")
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
$LogServicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$LogAppId'"
$AppRole = $LogServicePrincipal.AppRoles | 
Where-Object {$_.Value -eq $PermissionName -and $_.AllowedMemberTypes -contains "Application"}

New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $MSI.ObjectId -PrincipalId $MSI.ObjectId -ResourceId $LogServicePrincipal.ObjectId -Id $AppRole.Id
```

[image]

Check whether the **API permission is assigned to the managed identity** like below:

*Go to Enterprise Application -> Search your managed identity -> Permissions*

[image]

I assigned **Log Analytics Reader role** to the Managed Identity:

[image]

Now generate the **access token** using the below code:

```cs
using System;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Core;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string clientId = "XXXXXXXX"; // The Client ID of the user assigned identity

        AccessToken token = await new DefaultAzureCredential(
            new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
                ManagedIdentityClientId = clientId
            })
            .GetTokenAsync(
                new TokenRequestContext(
                    new[] { "https://westus2.api.loganalytics.io/.default" }
                ));

        Console.WriteLine(token.Token);
    }
}
```

[image]

***Decoded access token:***

[image]

Using the above generated access token, **I am able to access the Log Analytic workspace** successfully:

```json
https://api.loganalytics.io/v1/workspaces/WorkSpaceID/query
```

[image]

Comment: Here in the above solution, Is it possible to replace the .Net part by Angular or any modern frontend framework.